# Laravel custom class not found

Tags: php, laravel

I create a folder `Translators` inside the `App` folder.

In the `Translators` i have `MyOwnClass.php`

The `App\Translators\MyOwnClass.php` code is:

```
<?
    
    namespace App\Translators;
    
    
    class MyOwnClass{
    
        public function home()    {
            dd("Hello World);
        }

    }
```

In the controller where I need it I used this code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Translators\MyOwnClass;


class MachineController extends Controller
{
    public function home(){

        $machine = (New MyOwnClass);
    }
}
```

I run the `composer dump-autoload` command

In the composer.json there's the:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
        "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
    }
},
```

But when I reach the MachineController::home I get error:

```
Class "App\Translators\MyOwnClass" not found
```

What I'm missing??

Comment: Is `short_open_tag` enabled? Have you tried `<?php` instead of `<?`?

Comment: OMG....I feel so stupid at the moment. Thank you so much!